# Button onlick event doesn't work

Tags: javascript, html

I'm creating a small tic-tac-toe game, so far it is just a table of buttons, when you click on a button it will display the value (whether 'X' or 'O'). Here is the code:

```js
function play(){
  var dimension = parseInt(document.getElementById("dimension").value);
  var winCondition = parseInt(document.getElementById("win-condition").value);
  var board = document.getElementById('space');
  table = document.createElement('table');
  board.appendChild(table);

  for (var i = 0; i < winCondition; i++) {
    var row = table.insertRow(i);
    for (var j = 0; j < winCondition; j++) {
      var cell = row.insertCell(j);
      button = document.createElement("button");
      cell.appendChild(button);
      button.style.height = '50px';
      button.style.width = '50px';
      button.style.border = 'none';
      button.style.backgroundColor = '#333';
      button.style.color = '#000';
      button.addEventListener("click", function(){
        button.innerHTML = "X";
      });
    }
  }

  document.getElementById("play").onclick = false;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Tic Tac Toe</title>
  <script src="application.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <p>Enter dimension: <br><input type="text" id="dimension"></p>
  <p>Enter winning condition: <br><input type="text" id="win-condition"></p>
  <button type="submit" onclick="play()" id="play">Play</button>
  <div id="space"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

When I click on a random button, its innerHTML doesn't change. The only button that change is the last button, although I didn't click on that.

One more question: how can you get the id of the button in order to check win condition? For example, can you do `button[i].value`?

P.s: I don't use jQuery, thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Issue is `button` is an object. So it will be passed as reference.

Also since you are not use `var` to define it, its global. So when you do `button.innerHTML`, it points to last button.

You should use `this.innerHTML = 'X'`

**Sample Code**

```js
function play(){
  var dimension = parseInt(document.getElementById("dimension").value);
  var winCondition = parseInt(document.getElementById("win-condition").value);
  var board = document.getElementById('space');
  table = document.createElement('table');
  board.appendChild(table);

  for (var i = 0; i < winCondition; i++) {
    var row = table.insertRow(i);
    for (var j = 0; j < winCondition; j++) {
      var cell = row.insertCell(j);
      var button = document.createElement("button");
      cell.appendChild(button);
      button.style.height = '50px';
      button.style.width = '50px';
      button.style.border = 'none';
      button.style.backgroundColor = '#333';
      button.style.color = '#000';
      button.addEventListener("click", function(){
        this.innerHTML = "X";
      });
    }
  }

  document.getElementById("play").onclick = false;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Tic Tac Toe</title>
  <script src="application.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <p>Enter dimension: <br><input type="text" id="dimension"></p>
  <p>Enter winning condition: <br><input type="text" id="win-condition"></p>
  <button type="submit" onclick="play()" id="play">Play</button>
  <div id="space"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Also as a suggestion, instead of using `button.style...` multiple times, define a *css class* and just add this class to elements. This will make you code cleaner.

Also, instead of having an inline function, create a named function and pass its reference. This will make sure multiple copies of same function is not created.

```js
function play() {
  var dimension = parseInt(document.getElementById("dimension").value);
  var winCondition = parseInt(document.getElementById("win-condition").value);
  var board = document.getElementById('space');
  table = document.createElement('table');
  board.appendChild(table);

  for (var i = 0; i < winCondition; i++) {
    var row = table.insertRow(i);
    for (var j = 0; j < winCondition; j++) {
      var cell = row.insertCell(j);
      var button = document.createElement("button");
      button.classList.add("myButton");
      cell.appendChild(button);
      button.addEventListener("click", handleClick);
    }
  }

  document.getElementById("play").onclick = false;
}

function handleClick() {
  this.innerHTML = "X";
}
```

```css
.myButton {
  height:50px;
  width:50px;
  border:none;
  background-color:#333;
  color: #eee;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Tic Tac Toe</title>
  <script src="application.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <p>Enter dimension: <br><input type="text" id="dimension"></p>
  <p>Enter winning condition: <br><input type="text" id="win-condition"></p>
  <button type="submit" onclick="play()" id="play">Play</button>
  <div id="space"></div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

This will work

```js
var counter=0;
function play(){
  var dimension = parseInt(document.getElementById("dimension").value);
  var winCondition = parseInt(document.getElementById("win-condition").value);
  var board = document.getElementById('space');
  table = document.createElement('table');
  board.appendChild(table);

  for (var i = 0; i < winCondition; i++) {
    var row = table.insertRow(i);
    for (var j = 0; j < winCondition; j++) {
      var cell = row.insertCell(j);
      button = document.createElement("button");
      cell.appendChild(button);
      button.style.height = '50px';
      button.style.width = '50px';
      button.style.border = 'none';
      button.style.backgroundColor = '#333';
      button.style.color = '#000';
      button.addEventListener("click", function(){
      
      if(this.innerHTML !="")
        return;
      else if(counter%2==0)
        this.innerHTML ="x";
      else if(counter%2==1)
        this.innerHTML ="0";
      counter+=1;
      });
    }
  }

  document.getElementById("play").onclick = false;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Tic Tac Toe</title>
  <script src="application.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <p>Enter dimension: <br><input type="text" id="dimension"></p>
  <p>Enter winning condition: <br><input type="text" id="win-condition"></p>
  <button type="submit" onclick="play()" id="play">Play</button>
  <div id="space"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please notice `<>` icon in editor. You can create a executable snippet(*only HTML, CSS and JS though*). You can also indent your code as well.

Comment: Learned a new thing on so. Iron Man says thanks captain:)